# How can I make my signup script check for payment validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, paypal-ipn

```js
//Users Registration Function
function vpb_users_registration() 
{
 var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
 var vpb_fullname = $("#fullname").val();
 var vpb_username = $("#username").val();
 var vpb_email = $("#email").val();
 var vpb_passwd = $("#passwd").val();
 
 if(vpb_fullname == "")
 {
  $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your fullname in the required field to proceed.</div>');
  $("#fullname").focus();
 }
 else if(vpb_username == "")
 {
  $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your desired username to proceed.</div>');
  $("#username").focus();
 }
 else if(vpb_email == "")
 {
  $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your email address to proceed.</div>');
  $("#email").focus();
 }
 else if(reg.test(vpb_email) == false)
 {
  $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter a valid email address to proceed.</div>');
  $("#email").focus();
 }
 else if(vpb_passwd == "")
 {
  $("#signup_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your desired password to go.</div>');
  $("#passwd").focus();
 }
 else
 {
  var dataString = 'vpb_fullname='+ vpb_fullname + '&vpb_username=' + vpb_username + '&vpb_email=' + vpb_email + '&vpb_passwd=' + vpb_passwd + '&page=signup';
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "vpb_save_details.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function() 
   {
    $("#signup_status").html('<br clear="all"><br clear="all"><div align="left"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:black;">Please wait</font> <img src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Loading...." align="absmiddle" title="Loading...."/></div><br clear="all">');
   },
   success: function(response)
   {
    var vpb_result_broght = response.indexOf('completed');
    if (vpb_result_broght != -1 ) 
    {
     $("#fullname").val('');
     $("#username").val('');
     $("#email").val('');
     $("#passwd").val('');
     $("#signup_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
    }
    else
    {
     $("#signup_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
    }
    
   }
  });
 }
}

//Users Login Function
function vpb_users_login() 
{
 var vpb_username = $("#username").val();
 var vpb_passwd = $("#passwd").val();
 
 if(vpb_username == "")
 {
  $("#login_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your account username to proceed.</div>');
  $("#username").focus();
 }
 else if(vpb_passwd == "")
 {
  $("#login_status").html('<div class="info">Please enter your account password to go.</div>');
  $("#passwd").focus();
 }
 else
 {
  var dataString = 'vpb_username=' + vpb_username + '&vpb_passwd=' + vpb_passwd + '&page=login';
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "vpb_save_details.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function() 
   {
    $("#login_status").html('<br clear="all"><br clear="all"><div align="left"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:black;">Please wait</font> <img src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Loading...." align="absmiddle" title="Loading...."/></div><br clear="all">');
   },
   success: function(response)
   {
    var vpb_result_broght = response.indexOf('completed');
    if (vpb_result_broght != -1 ) 
    {
     $("#login_status").html('');
     $("#username").val('');
     $("#passwd").val('');
     window.location.replace("index1.php");
     
    }
    else
    {
     $("#login_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(response);
    }
    
   }
  });
 }
}
```

I want my signup form to check if payment was processed before saving the user credentials to the database which will gain them access to the member section. once payment is processed I want the user's information to log them into thier account. the way i have my code setup is so that the usernames/database saved in a txt file on the hosting site.

Comment: I hope you're not handling your payments as poorly as you are user authentication, but aside from that, you haven't shown us anything about how your payments are taken or stored so it is impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

What you posted has nothing to do with payment, credit card numbers, etc. I only see full name, user name, password, email. Looks like functionality to log in or create a user.

On the server side you have to have some code for the merchant processing (PHP for example) and it should return a disposition telling you if the charge was successful or not. If you don't have code implemented for Paypal already, I'd recommend using Stripe, they have low 2.9% fees and no monthly fees and it's extremely easy to implement.

In Javascript, on the client side, you could use the $.post method, or $.ajax like you're doing already in your call to `vbp_save_details.php`

Personally, I use the $.post method. On the server, my payment processing script returns a json object letting you know if it was approved or not. Something like this:

```
$.post('stripe.php',payload,
    function(data) {
        $('#submit_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json);
        if ( json.disposition == 1 ) {
            console.log("APPROVED");
            window.location.href = "thank_you.php";
        } else {
            console.log("DECLINED");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: i dont have a payment setup yet

Comment: it is setup bad i know having trouble making it so the signup page wont automatically activate/store username in database

Comment: I would consider an all in one membership payment solution, such as making a Wordpress website using the [Simple Membership](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-membership/) plugin for paid members areas. This already supports Paypal. If you need help with your project, PM me, I have already written automated m3u8 recording software.